# How to pass a parameter in react native navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I tried an example of React Native Navigator:

```
const StudentStackNav = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
     screen: StudentLogin,
    }
});
```

How do I pass a parameter to StudentStackNav and pass it to StudentLogin?

I have tried `<StudentStackNav name='Lucy'>` but `this.props.name` is not available in `Home`.

Comment: Take a look at "Getting Started" , "Passing Params" section: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/#Passing-params

Comment: @Cherniv Actually, I want to pass a parameter to a Navigator rather than a screen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Normal props on a Navigator component can be used to configure the navigator.

To send arbitrary props to the screens, you have to use `screenProps`.

So for example:

```
<StudentStackNav screenProps={{ name: 'Lucy' }}/>
```

Which will be available in `StudentLogin` as `this.props.screenProps`.

**`screenProps` is documented on [this page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props)**

Comment: This answer is correct, and much more useful than the documentation on the react native site. As a note, you can access these properties from a constructor in a class as well even though few people seem to do it:
`class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
   super(props);
                        props.screenProps // what you want to access
  }
    render() {
        return null;
    }
}`